# Рейтинг статей по типу "мне нравится"

Tags: php, mysql

Решил сделать  для сайта кнопку по типу "мне нравится", как в соц. сетях. Собственно нужен алгоритм осуществления этой задачи. Вот вариант который пока пришел в голову: В БД в таблице статей есть поля like, id_user, hash (к примеру), в поле like естественно кол-во "мне нравится" для статьи, в поле id_user, id человека который нажал на кнопку, и hash это автоматически присваиваемый хэш для статьи. На самом сайте ссылка "мне нравится" будет иметь вид mysite.ru/news?like=af1s4a7ds2a4g6afd6f. Далее при нажатии на кнопку будет сверятся хэш af1s4a7ds2a4g6afd6f со значением в базе для этой статьи, если сходится ставим этой статье в поле like +1. Если есть вариант намного проще и легче осуществить эту задачу, слушаю ваши предложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант... Можно завести таблицу  like c полями `like_id`, `like_user_id`, `like_unick`. Потом в таблице статей сделать столбец `like_unick`, сделать связь с таблицей like. И про получении статьи из БД INNER JOIN'ом делать count лайков в таблице like (`like_unick` нам известен). А при нажатии на кнопку нравится, просто дописывать в таблицу Like одну строчку с `user_id` нажавшем на кнопку и `like_unick`, присущем для ДАННОЙ СТАТЬИ. Сделайте PRIMARY KEY на `like_id`,`like_unick` и INDEX на `like_user_id`. Должно работать все быстро. Столбец `Like_unick` желательно сделать обычным int'ом.

А то что описали Вы, никак не вяжется со структурой таблицы статей. Там должна быть всего одна строчка на одну статью. Иначе никак...

Comment: like_unick это я так понял уникальный номер статьи, хэш то бишь?

Comment: Да... Только hash'ом (т.е. строкой) его делать нежелательно. Лучше сделайте обычным int'ом. Иначе выбирать будет долго. И в целом будет снижение производительности.

Comment: тогда проверка нужна какая нибудь, чтоб путем подмены url нельзя было ставить +1

Comment: Но ведь хэш также можно подменить, как и обычный int. Только смысл? Если ты зарегистрированный пользователь, если ты не голосовал еще за эту статью, и если такая статья существует в списке статей, то ставим +1